# How to use django admin to automatically select the model ？？

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

For example, there are 3 models, task, car, driver. task has two foreign keys, car and driver. Car OneToOneField driver. After the task select the car, how to automatically correspond to the driver, in the admin interface？？ thank you all

Comment: Forms automatically fill

Comment: Why you want to do this? if car have a onetoone to driver make task to only have a foreignkey to car (so you have the driver too)! else explain better what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to bind car and driver, select the car can only select the associated driver

Comment: Then what do you mean by: After the task select the car, how to automatically correspond to the driver

Comment: If the car and driver binding, task can only be a single car (drive), or two need to choose

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to say @Ma Mars

Comment: Yes, the key is whether there is a binding between car and driver

Comment: can you share some code (that you already have) and a pseudo code of what you are trying to achieve?